# Remote Access to Ubuntu (as guest OS) from Linux Mint (as host OS) in VirtualBox with ssh

Tags: networking, permissions, virtualbox, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to access remotely to Ubuntu virtual OS from the host OS which in this case is linux Mint. My Ubuntu version has no GUI, just a terminal interface.

And change the network setting in virtual OS setting like this:

> Network adapter is enabled. 
>   Attached-to Host-only Adapter 
>   vboxnet()

I run the virtual OS and login. Then via terminal in my host OS i do like this:

> ssh -v -Y localhost@192.168.56.1 
>   localhost@192.168.56.1's password: 
>   Permission denied, please try again. 
>   localhost@192.168.56.1's password: 
>   Permission denied (public key, password)

What is wrong and how i can access it remotely?

**Update: detailed log**

```
myusername@linuxmint ~ $ ssh -v -Y localhost@192.168.56.1
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.1 [192.168.56.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 63:3c:9e:9c:c7:fd:dd:8c:51:ed:1b:e1:54:bf:39:93
debug1: Host '192.168.56.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

It still doesn't work. It seems the problem in the public key. What is that? Sorry, i'm still new about this.

Answer (score 0):

Password auth is disabled on the SSH server by default. You first have to enable it. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

If the problem continue to exist, examine the sshd log file first.

Also note that you have to provide your login name, not the server name:
ssh -v -Y **username**@192.168.56.1

Comment: It still said permission denied (public key). Seems like no difference with the first one. It just keep asking `key`

Comment: sshd log output?

Comment: Sorry, where is that?

Comment: Just read the troubleshooting guide in the link I posted above. Also look at the sshd log in /var/log

Comment: - is your username really "localhost"?
- did you restart the sshd after updating the config file?

Comment: Yes, username for the one in VirtualBox is name@localhost. And yes, i did restart. I'm using blank ubuntu from [instalinux](http://www.instalinux.com/). So, there's no GUI.

Comment: @M.AwadSyahid Then you should run `ssh -Y name@192.168.56.1`